# Determining duplicate values before a form is submitted

Tags: javascript, ajax

Say I have an online form, and I want to figure out whether a user is entering an email that's already in use by the system. Can I tell the system to check the field against the database as soon as the user moves their cursor / selection away from the field? Could anyone point me in the right direction if this is actually possible?

Comment: Yes. You can use onblur event handler, and ajax to send/receive data without page refreshing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this You need to call ajax when user writing an email id means on blur event as below :

```
    $('#yourfieldID').blur(function() {
       var val = $(this).val();
       $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'your url',
                data: {email: val},
                success: function (data) {
                    // check for response
                    });
                }
            });
    });
```

Now In file which you called in ajax url, Your need to check data which is exist in database or not and according to that you need to send response and check it in sucess part of ajax call.

I hope you will get it.

Answer (score 4):

You could attach a listener to the text field using jQuery's [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur) event, like so:

```
$('#MyEmailField').blur(function() {
  // jQuery AJAX Call here, $.ajax(...)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using an AJAX call on the "onblur" event of Javascript (or "focusout" method of jQuery)

You could use something like this, in the HTML:

```
<input type="email" name="myinput" />
```

And the JS:

```
$( "input" ).focusout(function() {
    var usr_email = $(this).value;
    $.ajax({
       method: "GET",
       url: "some.php",
       data: { email: usr_email }
    }).done(function( response ) {
       if(response == "taken"){
         $("input").borderColor = "red";
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for email's availability through an Ajax call in database on text change or blur event of email textbox. Then notify the user accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as user moves out of email field, say tab or mouse click, you need to trigger a function to make a Ajax call to your server. The triggering function would be onBlur of email  field.  Then check If user email exits,  get back Ajax response to notify the user.